# Javascript adding fields dynamically (onClick)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do add some fields dynamically. For example, when the user clicks the checkbox, or radio button, some extra fields will be appeared (buttons, textfields, etc.). Can I do this with onClick if yes how can I do that ?

Thank you!

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to modify the DOM using Javascript. You need to learn the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it,

have the elements you want to appear precoded in html but hidden using css.

For example:

```js
 // If enyone "change" the magic checkbox, ... I will know it
document.getElementById('magic_checkbox').addEventListener('change', function(){

 // Is it checked... because if it is,
 // I should show the more inputs
 if(this.checked){
  document.getElementById('some_more_data').style.display = "block";
 }

 // If it is unchecked
 // I should hide them
 else{
  document.getElementById('some_more_data').style.display = "none";
 }

}, false);
```

```html
<!-- The mahic check box -->
<input id="magic_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="something" value="a_value"> Do you want more?<br>

<!-- My hidden inputs -->
<div id="some_more_data" style="display:none;">
 <input type="text" name="other_data_no1" value="Yeah!"><br>
 <input type="text" name="other_data_no2" value="Fill me!">
</div>

<!-- Some other data -->
<input type="number" name="something_else" value="123"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the buttons already in the website and just hide them using some form of:

```
<button style="display: none"></button>
```

Then you can show them and hide them as needed.

### Pros

- You can style the button, textfield, etc beforehand and fit it into the website how you wish via CSS
- You can remove them with another function that hides the element
- No messy JS

### Cons

- None really...

### Example of Implementation

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <style>
            #button2 {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="show('button2')">Click Me!</button>
        <button id="button2">Click Me!</button>
        <script>
            function show(element) {
                document.getElementById(element).style.display = block;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The cons are that you may post useles data on the server if all that are used inside a form. But not a big one :P

Answer (score 0):

You can. This code copied form: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");       // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);                                // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);                    // Append <button> to <body>
```